# Isomorphism of group rings

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, fourier-transform, abelian-groups, group-rings

I have to prove that $G=\mathbb{Z}/6\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}/12$ are not isomorphic, but the group rings $\mathbb{C}[H]$ and $\mathbb{C}[G]$ are isomporphic. First part was quite easy. Second part is a bit trickier for me. I know that $\mathbb{C}[H]=\{\sum_{h\in H}Z_hh|Z_h\in\mathbb{C}\}$ and similarly $\mathbb{C}[G]=\{\sum_{g\in G}Z_gg|Z_g\in\mathbb{C}\}$. I tried defining a general isomorphism from $\phi:\mathbb{C}[G]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{|G|}$ by $\phi(\sum_{\in G}Z_gg)$ is the vector of coefficients, but I don't think it works. I thought that this has something to do with the fact that the field of complex numbers is algebraiclly closed, but I feel like I'm missing some basic properties of such group rings.

We did define the dual group $G^*$ the fourier transfrom of finite abellian groups, but I don't know if this has anything to do with the question itself.
Any hint would help, even some formal properties that might help me find the  solution myself.

Comment: Can you map each element of $G$ to a corresponding element of $H$? Elements of group algebras are just these formal sums over all elements of the group, so you don't run into the problem you no doubt encountered when considering $G$ and $H$.

Comment: @bounceback like mapping an element in $\mathbb{C}[G]$ to the corresponding element with the same coefficients in $\mathbb{C}[H]$? This is confusing to me because we are not using any property of $\mathbb{C}$, while I do know that in some cases two group rings may be isomorphic when the ring is the complex numbers field, but not when the ring is the real numbers field.

Comment: Ok, but do you run into that problem in this case?

Comment: @bounceback what actions exactly should the isomorphism respect in this case? the formal sum and the multiplication that is defined like the groups action?

Comment: So this shows that the group ring functor is not faithful, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

By Maschke's Theorem both algebras are semisimple. Now Wedderburn's Theorem tells us that as $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed any abelian group $G$ with $n$ elements must give $\mathbb{C}(G)\cong M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C})\times...\times M_{n_k}(\mathbb{C})\overset{G \text{ abelian}}{\cong}\underset{n \text{ times}}{\mathbb{C}\times...\times\mathbb{C}}$ as the $n_i$ represent the number of  elements in each conjugacy class of $G$.

Comment: We have not proved this theorem in class. Is there any direct isomorphism I can obtain here?

Comment: Ok I will leave the answer as a reference if anyone has the same problem later. Personally based on this answer I would try to show both of them are ismorphic to the product $\mathbb{C}\times...\mathbb{C}$

Comment: That was my first approach but I don't understand how it used the fact that the complex field is algebraicllly closed

Comment: Well in the proof above it is a result by Maschke and Wedderburn, in particular a semisimple  k-algebra can be written as $ M_{n_1}(D_1)\times...\times M_{n_i}(D_i)$ where $D_i$ are division rings. In the case of $k$ being algebraically closed these $D_i$ are exactly $k$. Then you will get $M_{n_1}(k)\times...M_{n_i}(k)$ and if any dimension is larger than $1$ you get a ring of matrices which will contain a non abelian element of the k-algebra